# Collect json data and output into AJAX div

Tags: arrays, json, ajax, function

I'm wondering how its possible to send all the below data into the div as you can see I have given it a go and the call is made and I collect all correct data, but my div's aren't updating. So its obviously a client side issue.

```
{{"notifications":
[
"num":"1",
"title":"681",
"url":"Lucy  Botham posted a status on your wall"
"urlf":"singlepoststreamitem.php?streamitem_id=556"
"urlfy":"85"
"urlfyf":"2015-11-06 16:30:52"
},]}
{{"notifications":
[
"num":"1",
"title":"682",
"url":"Lucy  Botham posted a status on your wall"
"urlf":"singlepoststreamitem.php?streamitem_id=557"
"urlfy":"85"
"urlfyf":"2015-11-06 16:30:54"
},]}
{{"notifications":
[
"num":"1",
"title":"683",
"url":"Lucy  Botham posted a status on your wall"
"urlf":"singlepoststreamitem.php?streamitem_id=558"
"urlfy":"85"
"urlfyf":"2015-11-06 16:30:55"
},]}
```

I will refrain from posting irrelevant code to the question as I know its just in the success where I'm having problems. I'm new to this method so maybe a little bit of commenting to describe my errors.

```
    dataType:"json",
    success: function(data){

    $.each(notifications, function(i,data)
    {
    var div_data =
    <div class='notif_text'><div id='notif_actual_text-' class='notif_actual_text'>
    <img border='1' src='userimages/cropped'"+notifications[i].notification_triggeredby+"'.jpg' 
onerror=this.src='userimages/no_profile_img.jpeg' width='40' height='40' ><br />
    <a href=''"+notifications[i].notification_throughurl+"''>'"+notifications[i].notification_content+"'</a>
    <br />'"+notifications[i].notification_time+"'<br/></div></div></div><hr/>";
    if(notifications[i].notification_id>notification_id){

    $(div_data).prepend("#notif_ui"+notifications[i].notification_id);
    }
    });
     i = 
    parseInt($("#mes").text());$("#mes").text((i+notifications[i].num));
```

Comment: It would indeed be possible, **if** it was valid JSON ... Also there seem to be no connection with your code attempt and the values in the invalid JSON? Completely different attribute names, so how to know where to put each items?

Comment: For starters, you're missing the opening " in div_data = <div

Comment: Is there any chance I could get a bit of help on how to actually do it then? Please. Thank you